# Android app hangs during boot sequence when letter is present in versionName field

Tags: android, xml, manifest, freeze

Whenever any character that’s not numerical (or a period) is entered into the versionName field in the AndroidManifest.xml file of my app, it will hang during the boot sequence and never progress to the log in screen. This occurs whether or not there is a numerical character in that field.

In the below example, I added an “x” to “2.5.0”. I've tried this with just letters, different words, different alpha-numeric combinations and it’s always the same result. My app will boot, but will be unable to get past the boot sequence. The app will just hang on the loading animation and never progress to the log in screen:

```
<manifest android:versionCode="33" android:versionName="2.5.0x" android:installLocation="auto" package="com.general.example"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

The versionName is displayed within the app; could there be a problem with displaying letters for some odd reason?

If you need more information, such as the full manifest file please let me know. I changed the “package” field to hide what app this is. Full disclosure, I have a very basic understanding of code, so please keep that in mind when explaining what may be occurring. I’m looking into this because I’m investigating how another app interacts with our app and and why it was causing our app not to get past the boot sequence. But it seems that the cause is what I described above. Their app modifies the versionName field to add the name of their app. However, I've tested this with unmodified code by simply adding a letter or a word, or deleting the number altogether and just using a word (ex. Alpha) and received the same result.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post the code you use to display the version name

Comment: I'm assuming you mean PackageInfo, correct? What file would I find that in? Or am I just way off?